# XPATH - find nodes of a type - don`t search childs

Tags: xml, xpath

i would can`t find out how to:

1 Scenario: find in given example only the parent nodes (incl. all children) "bone" - bone#1, bone#2, bone#3, not the others.

1. Scenario: find in given example all 'bones' but keep hiearchy intact with removing the nodes (one in the example) between which are not bones.

Example (parent bones do not have to be in the same level:

```
<node>
    <bone id="1">
        <bone id="1.2">
            <node>
                <bone id="1.3">
                    <bone id="1.4"></bone>
                </bone>
            </node>
        </bone>
    </bone>
    <node>
        <bone id="2"></bone>
    </node>
    <bone id="3"></bone>
</node>
```

Thanks in advance,
alex

Comment: Where is that "given example"? And how far have you come when trying for yourself?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "but keep hiearchy intact with removing the nodes between". Can you give an example of the desired output for each scenario?

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, this query may help you : `//bone[not(ancestor::bone)]`